# Is it possible for a .NET process to be started without Event Counters?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, diagnostics, etw

I have an app that attempts to establish an EventPipe session with some .NET Core processes in order to get an access to their Event Counters.

The code uses [Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/main/documentation/diagnostics-client-library-instructions.md):

```cs
    var processId = ...; // guaranteed to exist
    var providers = new List<EventPipeProvider>()
    {
        new EventPipeProvider(
            "System.Runtime",
            EventLevel.Informational,
            (long)ClrTraceEventParser.Keywords.None,
            new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "EventCounterIntervalSec", "1" }
            }
        )
    };
    var client = new DiagnosticsClient(processId);
    using(var session = client.StartEventPipeSession(providers))
    {
        // ..
    }
```

It works fine in most of the cases, but sometimes the call to `StartEventPipeSession` hangs and times out. Retrying doesn't help. However, the process, which refuses to have an EventPipe Session connected, looks pretty normal apart from that and it works as expected.

Is it possible for a .NET Core process to be started without Event Counters?

I use Windows 10.

#### EDIT

As suggested in the comments, here's an exception message that I get from `StartEventPipeSession`. Nothing too fancy, just a timeout, but I post it here for completeness.

```
EXCEPTION: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 startTime)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.IpcEndpointHelper.Connect(IpcEndpointConfig config, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.PidIpcEndpoint.Connect(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.IpcClient.SendMessageGetContinuation(IpcEndpoint endpoint, IpcMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.EventPipeSession.Start(IpcEndpoint endpoint, EventPipeSessionConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.DiagnosticsClient.StartEventPipeSession(IEnumerable`1 providers, Boolean requestRundown, Int32 circularBufferMB)
```

Comment: Did you check event viewer to see details of the error?

Comment: Nothing interesting under `Windows Logs\Application`. Is there any other location worth checking?

Comment: Is this your posting? https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/4557

Comment: Yes, I posted it two days ago. In the meantime I worked out that names of .exe files has no impact, unlike I had initially assumed.

Comment: What I found out is that the more my CPU is loaded the more likely this issue is to occur.

Comment: In your link there is following code : { "EventCounterIntervalSec", "1" }  increase interval and see what happens.  I would also add to the exception handler a THROW so when an exception occurs in the git-hub code you can capture the exception in your code.   Without the throw you do not know when an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The exception that I see (using the method you described) is just regarding a timeout while attempting to create a NamedPipe. Hang on, I'll post add it to the question.

Comment: A network timeout exception isn't "just", it says that the remote server (or process in this case) didn't allow the connection. And yes, `the more my CPU is loaded the more likely this issue is to occur` a process under high stress may not have the time to handle low priority connections. Event counters are a metrics mechanism that shouldn't burden the application itself. If the runtime has to decide whether to process application work  or return a counter that represents the number of processed requests, the application has higher priority

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Event counters are the legacy-legacy way of generating metrics. . The current way is to use OpenTelemetry which, in .NET 8, is baked into the BCL itself. Instead of building your own monitoring agent you can use any of the monitoring server products that support OpenTelemetry like Jaeger, Prometheus, Honeycomb, Elastic, desktop products like OpenTelemetry Desktop Viewer or .NET Aspire's dashboard. Perhaps you should check the [.NET Getting Started guide](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/net/getting-started/)

Comment: You can *reduce* the monitoring overhead too by caching and sampling traces and metrics, or using the [OpenTelemetry Collector](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/quick-start/) to collect the data from multiple services/apps and present it to monitoring tools

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the hints. From my side (1) By "just" I meant that it doesn't provide any message other then "connection refused". (2) Regarding priorities between the application and the metrics - do you think it is possible for an application not to initialize the internal Event Counters when it's spawned under a heavy load?

Comment: And I've been trying to do? A simple answer is: maintain an existing system. I'm aware of the fact that the Event Counters are not the most recent technology, but rewriting the module to another library would require a significant time budget.